# How to integrate PCL library into an existing project?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcl, perception-pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I clone the [hector_slam project](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam) in my catkin_ws:

1. `cd ~/catkin_ws/src/ && git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam`.
2. `cd .. && catkin_make`

Those two steps work perfectly and I can launch the program.

Now, I need to extend the project and need the PCL library `pcl_ros` https://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros to create new point clouds objects (for clustering and filtering), since `hector_slam` doesn't depend on the pcl_ros. `hector_slam` utilized `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::projectLaser()` to create a sensor_msgs::PointCloud.

Adding `#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>` in a source file returns this error `fatal error: pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: No such file or directory  #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>`

After adding `pcl_conversions` in the `find_package` line of CMakeLists.txt, it returns a CMake error of no package found.

Shall I install the package using `sudo apt install ros-melodic-pcl-conversions` or `sudo apt install pcl-ros` or clone the this github repo https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl in my `catkin_ws/src`?

It is a little bit confusing since the name in the Wiki https://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros called `pcl_ros` but the repo name is `perception_pcl`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363532/how-to-integrate-pcl-library-into-an-existing-project?/) by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2020-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest do always install dependencies via `apt`, if there is not a very specific reason to build from source.
Thus, install the dependency `ros-melodic-pcl-conversions` (as this is what you want to include) via apt (any dependencies of that will automatically be installed as well, another advantage vs. from source builds) and you should be good to go.

`perception_pcl` is only the repository, that contains the packages `pcl_conversions`, `pcl_ros` and the `perception_pcl` [metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages). You can install any package alone (besides dependencies, obviously) via apt. But if you want to build from source, you obviously need to fetch the full repo.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-16**:
thanks @mgruhler